# How to get data from Archived contracts in DAML using nodejs bindings?

Tags: node.js, daml

I wanted to get the history data from the archived contracts in DAML so that it can be used for audit purpose.
I read about JSON API services but it is only able to.

https://docs.daml.com/json-api/index.html

1. Create
2. Exercise
3. Query Active Contracts.

I was going through nodejs binding of DAML and found "Interface ArchivedEvent" but was not able to understand how to leverage it for getting the data.
https://digital-asset.github.io/daml-js/latest/interfaces/archivedevent.html

Answer (score 1):

> This is the sample piece of code through which i was able to fetch all the template data.

PackageCatalog contains the JSON of all the templateID

> templateId: {
>           packageId: 'my-package-id',
>           moduleName: 'SomeModule',
>           entityName: 'SomeTemplate'
>       },

```
const ledger = require('@digitalasset/daml-ledger'); 
const templateIds = require('../config/PackageCatalog.json')


const connect = util.promisify(ledger.DamlLedgerClient.connect.bind(ledger.DamlLedgerClient))
const client = await connect({ host: ' host id of your like localhost or some ip', port: 'your sandbox port number' })
const tmplt_Test = templateIds['Main.Test.Testuno:Testtemp']
const filtersByParty = {}
filtersByParty['Party Data you want to fetch'] = { inclusive: { templateIds: [tmplt_Test] } };
const GetTransactionsRequest = {
  begin: { offsetType: 'boundary', boundary: ledger.LedgerOffsetBoundaryValue.BEGIN },
  filter: { filtersByParty: filtersByParty }
};
let getAllTransactionData = client.transactionClient.getTransactions(GetTransactionsRequest);

getAllTransactionData.on('data', response => {
  console.log(" \n\n response :::: " + JSON.stringify(response))
  for (let transaction of response.transactions) {
    let events = transaction.eventsById;
    for (let eventId in events) {

    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ArchivedEvent` doesn't expose the argument with which the contract was initially created.

There are two possible approaches that you can take for auditing:

1. you can have a look at the [Extractor](https://docs.daml.com/tools/extractor.html), which dumps contracts on a RDBMS where you can query for archived contracts, or
2. write your app where you replay the transaction stream from the very beginning with [`TransactionService#getTransactions`](https://digital-asset.github.io/daml-js/latest/classes/nodejstransactionclient.html#gettransactions), save the contracts coming in as `CreatedEvent`s and then mark them as archived whenever you see an `ArchivedEvent`, using the contract identifier as reference.

Please note though that the Node.js bindings are currently a community-driven project so they may lag behind the latest releases.